# Adding basic http authorization in a ajax json script

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, basic-authentication

Not really sure how to add authentication in an ajax call for JSON information. I am trying to follow the examples given http://domainapi.com/documentation/how-to-use-domainapi/servuces-provided/domain-availability-api.html to check the availability of a domain name, however it keeps doing a http form pop up asking for username and password.

I thought I had everything right in my code:

```
function domainAvailabilityCheck(domain) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://api.domainapi.com/v1/availability/'+domain+'.com',
        beforeSend: setHeader,
        success: function(spitback) {
            console.log(spitback.content.domainList.status);
        },
        dataType:'jsonp'
    });
}

var setHeader = function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic YWtpcmF0ZXN0OmR0d3N0ZXN0');
}
```

Not sure what it is that I am doing wrong.

Comment: How did you compute the Basic Authentication header? Should be a base 64 encoding of the string literal username:password (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

Comment: @tozew that is probably my problem. I am using the basic authentication that was listed on the example page. Would generating my own http authentication fix my problem, and then what would you recommend for creating this string

Answer (score 0):

Your beforeSend isn't allowing Jquery to pass in the xhr object for the header modifications. The line should be

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequest(......); } // all-in-one, no extra function needed
```

or

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) { setHeader(xhr); } // call your separate function
```

Answer (score 0):

you may also:

```
var setHeader = function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic YWtpcmF0ZXN0OmR0d3N0ZXN0');
}

function domainAvailabilityCheck(domain) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://api.domainapi.com/v1/availability/'+domain+'.com',
        beforeSend: setHeader,
        success: function(spitback) {
            console.log(spitback.content.domainList.status);
        },
        dataType:'jsonp'
    });
}
```

actually it doesn't matter where to put the variable setHeader which holds the anonymous function, but this way up it's more readable (for me and my soft-compiler ... ;)